# Criar lista com conteúdo de colunas

Tags: python

Olá
Por favor, tenho um pandas.core.frame.DataFrame com essas colunas, no Python3:

```
Estado            150 non-null object
Cargo             150 non-null object
Nome_candidato    150 non-null object
CPF               150 non-null int64
Nome_urna         150 non-null object
Partido           150 non-null object
Situacao          150 non-null object
Avaliacao         130 non-null object
Projeto           150 non-null object
Link              72 non-null object
Autor_1           150 non-null object
Autor_1_limpo     150 non-null object
Autor_2           6 non-null object
Autor_2_limpo     6 non-null object
Autor_3           1 non-null object
Autor_3_limpo     1 non-null object
Autor_4           1 non-null object
Tipo              150 non-null object
Fonte             150 non-null object
```

Eu desejo criar uma lista só com o conteúdo da coluna Projeto. Fiz assim:

```
projetos_eleitos = []
for i in autor1:
    valor_projeto = i.Projeto 
    projetos_eleitos.append([valor_projeto])
```

### Com esse erro:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-c6845dcc0293> in <module>()
      1 for i in autor1:
----> 2     valor_projeto = i.Projeto
      3     projetos_eleitos.append([valor_projeto])
      4 

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'Projeto'
```

Alguém sabe qual é o erro?

Comment: O campo `valor_projeto` espera uma **String**, existe alguma propriedade que possa ser chamada após objeto **Projeto**? Ex: `valor_projeto = i.Projeto.nome` ou até mesmo realizar um **cast** : `valor_projeto = str(i.Projeto)`

Comment: Como está sendo definido `autor1`?

Comment: O erro diz: `i` se trata de uma `String` e o objeto `String` não possui nenhum atributo chamado `Projeto`. Como está sendo definido `autor1` ?

Comment: Obrigado a todos. Usei esse comando para pegar o conteúdo: valor_projeto = autor1.Projeto.tolist()
E autor1 estava definida assim: 
autor1 = pd.merge(eleitos_d_p, proj_isa, left_on='Nome_urna', right_on='Autor_1_limpo')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você está usando pandas não precisa usar um for...

Se você só quer transformar os projetos em uma lista, faça `df.Projeto.tolist()`

Por exemplo:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Autor': ['João', 'João', 'Maria', 'Maria', 'Joana'],
                   'Projeto': ['P'+str(i+1) for i in range(5)]})
print(df)

#    Autor Projeto
# 0   João      P1
# 1   João      P2
# 2  Maria      P3
# 3  Maria      P4
# 4  Joana      P5

print(df.Projeto.tolist())

['P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4', 'P5']
```

Agora, se você quiser agrupar os projetos por autor, pode gerar uma lista de listas

`df.groupby('Autor').apply(lambda grupo: grupo.Projeto.tolist()).tolist()`

Isso retorna `[['P5'], ['P1', 'P2'], ['P3', 'P4']]`

Uma desvantagem dessa abordagem é que você perde a referência do autor do projeto. Nesse caso uma opção é criar um dicionário:

`df.groupby('Autor').apply(lambda grupo: grupo.Projeto.tolist()).to_dict()`

O que gera `{'Joana': ['P5'], 'João': ['P1', 'P2'], 'Maria': ['P3', 'P4']}`

Comment: Obrigado. Assim funcionou: valor_projeto = autor1.Projeto.tolist()

Answer (score 0):

Talvez isso ajude:

```
projetos_eleitos = []

for i in autor1:
    projetos_eleitos.append( i['valor_projeto'] )
```